# File watch in Autosys

Tags: autosys

We have a SQL table that is populated by some jobs. The table structure is

```
ID  Date    Name
1   6/10/2017   sales
2   6/10/2017   marketing
3   6/17/2017   Loans
```

We recieve files on our server from vendors weekly.

For instance we received a file called **Sales_6/10/2017.txt**.

My autosys job need to watch this file and search it within table above. If the date and name matches in table then only further my job should run. If it doesn't find the entry in table then it must not run.

i am not able to figure out how to get this file watch along with checking with entry in table.

Answer (score 1):

Autosys can handle the file watcher, but it cannot execute a SQL query as a condition for starting a job. You should put that functionality into a shell script that is called by Autosys when the file arrives. The shell script should perform the query and then decide whether to proceed, depending on the results.

Comment: Thanks Erick, handled the table checking with shell script.